Using PySpark what is the fastest way of finding most frequent combinations that appears in list of list?
I am using a Databricks PySpark notebook. I am trying to find the most efficient way of finding the most frequent combinations in a list of lists. The number of combinations is 3.8 million and number of list of lists is 170000. I wrote an algorithm to do is this in stanard python, but when I fed in 10 lists this took 1 minute to process, so expanding that it would take 280 hours to process all lists. But since I have PySpark I think there may be a more efficient way of handling this, or a more efficient way of using standard python code - whichever works. I'd like to keep the processing time under 30 minutes, ideally 10.
Here is my current algorithm but inefficient at handling large number of lists:
from collections import defaultdict

combinations_of_n = [ ('a','b','c'), ('e','f','g'), ('h','i','j') ] # 3.8 million combinations
df_list = [ ['b','v','e','a','b','c'], ['g','g','a','b','c','f','b'], ['i','k','l','a','i','k'] ] # 170000 lists

# Count occurrences of each combination in lst_of_lsts
combination_count = defaultdict(int)

for sublist in df_list:
    for comb in combinations_of_n:
        if all(elem in sublist for elem in comb):
            combination_count[comb] += 1

# Find the top 5 most frequent combinations
top_combinations = sorted(combination_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:5]

# Print the results
print("Top 5 most frequent combinations:")
for comb, count in top_combinations:
    print(f"{comb}: {count} occurrences")

Any help appreciated

Do you have an actual real-world problem? These are some lowercase chars, seems unrealistic? If your actual problem is different, can you make your sample inputs and outputs almost similar to the actual problem? I fail to see any applications for this problem?

I don't think you need Pyspark; it seems plausible to me that you just need a more efficient algorithm. How about generating all combinations of 3 from each of the nested lists, then sorting all those and then counting how many instances of each one you have.

@user24714692 I dunno, "I can't imagine why you want to solve this problem" isn't a very strong argument for anything ... Agreed, anyway, that it would probably help if OP would say something about the real world problem, if any.

@RobertDodier The question includes sizes of 3.8M & 170K. The OP seems to be "masking" a real-world problem, or could be attempting to solve a "wrong problem".

@RobertDodier each character represents an action, I am trying to under what combination of actions is the most common.

@RobertDodier since each list represents actions I cant re-arrange them in a combination or that would tamper with the sequence of events.

If the cardinality (number) of actions is fairly low, you can make the filtering already terribly more efficient by a dict with an action as the key and a list of the sequences (or a set of indexes of sequences) containing said action as the value.

@joelion2 Thanks for the additional information. You should really put that in the problem description; bear in mind that you can help others help you.

For a quick improvement:
All your combinations and all your lists are in the form of arrays.
If you construct these as sets instead; then you should get some improvement as the checks to see if elements are contained will be faster.

I don't think you need PySpark for this at all.
As I alluded to in my comment, you can use a dict for indexing and set intersections to find the results.
On my machine, the original (orig_main) code takes about 1.5 minutes for the test data, and the new code is instantaneous. The results are different, though, because I think the original code has a bug where it mis-counts combinations like x,x,x, but that's up to you to decide (or it might be that my code has a bug too!).
With 150,000 combinations (not exactly 3.8 million) and 170,000 sequences, the new code is still instantaneous.
(You'll need the tqdm package for progress bars to run the below thing.)
import random
import string
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

import tqdm


def generate_test_data():
    actions = list(string.ascii_letters)
    n_combs = 50_000
    n_seqs = 10_000
    comb_len = 3
    seq_len = 6

    assert (
        n_combs < len(actions) ** comb_len
    ), "can't generate more combinations than mathematically possible"

    combinations_of_n = set()
    while len(combinations_of_n) < n_combs:
        combinations_of_n.add(
            tuple(random.choices(actions, k=comb_len))
        )

    dfs = set()
    while len(dfs) < n_seqs:
        dfs.add(tuple(random.choices(actions, k=seq_len)))

    return (combinations_of_n, dfs)


def print_result(combination_count):
    print("Top 5 most frequent combinations:")
    for comb, count in combination_count.most_common(5):
        print(f"{comb}: {count} occurrences")


def orig_main(combinations_of_n, dfs):
    combination_count = Counter()

    for df in tqdm.tqdm(dfs):
        for comb in combinations_of_n:
            if all(elem in df for elem in comb):
                combination_count[comb] += 1

    print_result(combination_count)


def new_main(combinations_of_n, dfs):
    # generate a mapping of action -> df indices
    dfs_by_actions = defaultdict(set)
    for df_index, df in enumerate(dfs):
        for action in df:
            dfs_by_actions[action].add(df_index)

    combination_count = Counter()

    for comb in tqdm.tqdm(combinations_of_n):
        # get the set of df indices that contain all elements of the combination
        df_indices = dfs_by_actions[comb[0]]
        for action in comb[1:]:
            df_indices &= dfs_by_actions[action]
        combination_count[comb] += len(df_indices)

    print_result(combination_count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    combinations_of_n, dfs = generate_test_data()
    orig_main(combinations_of_n, dfs)
    new_main(combinations_of_n, dfs)


